# python tests not deployed

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

I wrote a test that inherits from a built-in test, but it fails on my build server on an `ImportError`. When comparing the dev environment with the build server, and I get the following difference:

Dev environment (mac):

```
>>> len(os.listdir('/usr/lib/python2.7/test'))
1418
```

Build server (linux):

```
>>> len(os.listdir('/usr/lib/python2.7/test'))
8
```

Basically, when installing Python on the server, it didn't deploy Python's built-in test files. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Without any code or clues as to what you are actually doing it's impossible to answer this question.  Normally I'd mark it as "close to to lack of code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a package provided by your Linux distribution does not contains the entire set of test provided by the Python developers. Actually, in Debian and Ubuntu, package `libpython2.7-stdlib` contains only

- `pystone.py`
- `regrtest.py`
- `test_support.py`

as you can see in https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libpython2.7-stdlib/filelist.

In Debian and Ubuntu, the whole test suite is provided by the package `libpython2.7-testsuite`. Try to install it.

Alternatively, try to get the whole package from https://www.python.org/downloads/source/ and download the sources of your preferred version. Extract it: `./Python-2.7.x/Lib/test/` should contain all the files you need.